# Nearby messageLostHandler event every 5 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, beacon, google-nearby

I use Nearby to detect beacons. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setup];
[self startScanning];
}

-(void)setup {

[GNSMessageManager setDebugLoggingEnabled:YES];

void (^paramsBlock)(GNSMessageManagerParams *) = ^(GNSMessageManagerParams *params) {
    params.bluetoothPermissionErrorHandler = ^(BOOL hasError) {
        if (hasError) {
            NSLog(@"Nearby works better if Bluetooth use is allowed");
        }
    };
    params.bluetoothPowerErrorHandler = ^(BOOL hasError) {
        if (hasError) {
            NSLog(@"Nearby works better if Bluetooth is turned on");
        }
    };
};
_messageManager = [[GNSMessageManager alloc] initWithAPIKey:@"API-KEY" paramsBlock: paramsBlock]; 
}


- (void)startScanning {

// Create a subscription that scans for nearby beacons.
NSString *(^stringFromData)(NSData *) = ^(NSData *content) {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:content encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
};
GNSBeaconStrategy *beaconScanStrategy =
[GNSBeaconStrategy strategyWithParamsBlock:^(GNSBeaconStrategyParams *params) {
    params.includeIBeacons = NO;

}];
GNSMessageHandler messageFoundHandler = ^(GNSMessage *message) {

};
GNSMessageHandler messageLostHandler = ^(GNSMessage *message) {

};
_subscription = [_messageManager
                 subscriptionWithMessageFoundHandler:messageFoundHandler
                 messageLostHandler:messageLostHandler
                 paramsBlock:^(GNSSubscriptionParams *params) {
                     params.deviceTypesToDiscover = kGNSDeviceBLEBeacon;
                     params.beaconStrategy = beaconScanStrategy;
                     }];
}
```

Beacon is detect properly, but after every 5 minutes Nearby call messageLostHandler method and that:

> The message lost handler is called when a message is no longer observed (the device has gone out of range or is no longer publishing the message).

source: https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/pub-sub

Can someone tell me why this method is called every 5 minutes? I have to say that beacon and device stay in the same place, so I'm still in beacon area. 
Rest of Nearby features works fine.

It's so important to me, because when Nearby detect beacon I connect to him and make another actions. Someone have some ideas?

Comment: Does the beacon stop advertising when you connect to it?  Perhaps you can check with a beacon scanner app.

Comment: @davidgyoung I connect beacon with iPhone via Estimote app, when I use Nearby application on iPad and Nearby normally found beacon and after 5 minutes messageLostHandler called. Is it works fine?

Comment: If you DO NOT connect to the beacon using the Estimote app, does the messageLostHandler get called?

Comment: Yes, every time

Comment: If you leave your app running in the foreground, making sure not to let the screen go dark, does  messageLostHandler still get called after 5 minutes?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference if application is in foreground or background, it's crazy. Every time 5 minutes :/